# How to change button value attribute in JSP dynamically

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I currently have a MySQL database with a table 'description' containing a 'title' and 'contents' variables. What I'd like to do, is dynamically create buttons who's value attributes are the 'title' of each 'description' row. Then I'd like to have the buttons display the 'contents' value when their respective 'title' is clicked.

The problem is I'm not sure how to go about inserting a JSP String variable into a button 'value' attribute dynamically. Is there any way of doing this without javascript?

This is the code I have:

Getting the description objects:

```
<%
    List<Description> descriptions = DescriptionDB.getDescriptions();
%>
```

Scriptlet for the table of buttons:

```
<table border="1" id="titleTable">
                <%
                    if (descriptions != null) {
                        for (Description description : descriptions) {
                            String title = description.getDescriptionTitle();
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><a id="bt" type="button" value="title"</td>
                </tr>
                <%
                        }
                    }
                %>
            </table>
```

I would like the `value="title"` to be the `String title` in the scriptlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as

```
 %>
 <tr>
      <td><a id="bt" type="button" value="<%= title %>"</td>
 </tr>
 <%
```

Be aware though that the use of scriptlets seems to be considered sort of bad practice by some today.

Comment: try alternative way of Scriplets using EL or JSTL.